# What is the meaning of "would" here?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

The following sentence is given:

> I'd only just got into the bath when she phoned.

I cannot understand the meaning of "would". Is it a modal auxiliary here?

Comment: Where is **would**? If you're talking about **I'd**, that's **I had**.

Answer (score 1):

It is Past Perfect tense.

I (pronoun) had + v3 ... when she v2 (her phone call is at Past Simple).

Result of my action at the past when another person (she) did some action.